# AWS SESV2: sending an important email to a contact unsubscribed from all topics

Tags: boto3, amazon-ses

When using `{{amazonSESUnsubscribeUrl}}` in a template, there is the following option on the subscription preferences page:

[image]

This option promises that the contact who is unsubscribed from all topics will still receive important transactional and billing-related emails. How can I fulfill this promise? That is, how do I send an email to such a contact?

I tried not specifying the `ListManagementOptions` argument to [send_email](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sesv2/client/send_email.html) and the unsubscribed contact did not receive the email. Whatever topic I put as the `TopicName` in `ListManagementOptions`, he does not receive the email because he is unsubscribed from the topic. I am thinking that there might be a special `TopicName` reserved for this purpose, but have not been able to find anything to that end in the documentation.

So, how do I send important transactional and billing emails to a contact who unsubscribed from all topics?

P.S. The [question at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUMPpaBr_5So-bMwKlzdhQdQ/sending-an-important-email-to-a-contact-unsubscribed-from-all-topics)